# Keep getting "Unexpected token ," with coordinates in variables

Tags: javascript, google-maps, variables

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude from variable but I'm keep getting `Unexpected token ,`. I have tried to use `var coordinates = 59.328615,13.485699` and  `var coordinates = '59.328615,13.485699'` but I only got the same error. Now I'm out of ideas. What's wrong?!

```
var coordinate_latitude = 59.328615;
var coordinate_longitude = 13.485699;
var marker;
var gm_map;

function initialize() {
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(coordinate_latitude, coordinate_longitude);

    var googlemaps_options = {
        zoom: 18,
        minZoom: 4,
        maxZoom: 18,
        center: latlong,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        streetViewControl: false
    }

    gm_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-maps'), googlemaps_options);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlong,
        draggable: true,
        map: gm_map
    });
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    // INITIERA GOOGLE MAPS
    initialize();

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any `coordinates` variable in your example. Show us where you get the error, the actual code

Comment: @alestanis According to Google Chromes console the error is in `jquery.min.js` on line `2` (I'm fetching the jQuery file from Googles servers). But if I change `coordinate_latitude, coordinate_longitude` to `59.328615,13.485699` the error disappears and everything works just fine. So it's something with the variables and I don't know what it is :/

Comment: The variables are there; `var coordinates_latitude` and `var coordinates_longitude`

Comment: In **what** line of the code you showed us are you getting the error?

Comment: @alestanis Didn't I say where in other words than just a number? :S Anyway. Line 7.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EDzv5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Dr.Molle I got it working. geocodezip had also the correct answer but I'll use Dr.Molles solution (`initialize();` in `$(document(ready(function() { ...`). [Here is the working code](http://jsfiddle.net/EDzv5/).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the ready function to initialize the map.  The needs to be done in the load event once the page is rendered.  It works fine for me if I remove the jquery and do this instead:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

[Working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_unexpectedToken.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the same error occurred when I removed `initialize();` and added your load code below the function for initialize and over `$(document).ready(function() { ...`

Answer (score 0):

`var coordinates = 59.328615,13.485699` isn't valid JS.  It should be something like:

```
var coordinate_latitude = 59.328615, coordinate_longitude = 13.485699;
```

However the error message you're reporting doesn't bear any relation to the code you've posted (as pointed out by alestanis).  Your current code shouldn't error, or if it does, it must be a different error message than the one you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: What should it be then? The only thing that my code reacts to it the variables for the coordinates. I put my code to jsFiddle and I'm keep getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined` in `chrome-extension://odgmhaimkkjbnpmnpbgemphpcedcbbfd/myscript.js:1` :/ Link: http://jsfiddle.net/edgren/Pvr4K/